# Containerized kafka - cannot create transactions due to "Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId"

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

I am testing out a containerized kafka instance which I created with the following command:

```
docker run -d --name kafkacontainer -p 9093:9093 
-e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
-e KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1 
-e KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 
-e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=172.17.0.2:2181 
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://mytestvm:9093,BROKER://localhost:9092 
-e KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9093,BROKER://0.0.0.0:9092 
-e KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=BROKER 
-e KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=BROKER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT 
-e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_NUM_PARTITIONS=1 
-e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 
-e KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS=0 
confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
```

The instance works fine when I add a topic, send messages to the topic, and read from that topic.

Then, I attempted to create a transaction with the following code:

```
((KafkaProducer<?, ?>) producer).getInternalKafkaProducer().initTransactions();
```

This throws the following exception after hanging for 60 seconds:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId
```

After some googling, I found many posts suggesting that this error occurs because transactions require special configuration. Namely, there has to be multiple brokers, and multiple in-sync replicators (ISR). So I've tried configuring this setting pair below to no avail:

```
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1
```

I have tried 1/1, 3/2. What should they be in order to resolve this timeout error?

Comment: You need to use `-p 9092:9092` if you are trying to connect from outside of the container, but you already have those two variables in your first code block (and yes, they should be 1/1 for only a single broker)

Comment: @OneCricketeer 1/1 is not working for me sadly. Any suggestion on what else I can try to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: You could exec into the container to verify those two properties are actually in the broker properties. (should also be printed in the container log output when kafka is started) Otherwise, can you share more of your Java code as a [mcve]. I don't know what `getInternalKafkaProducer()` is for

Answer (score -1):

If you want to connect to kafka outside container, you need to publish outside port in docker container. Please, add -p 9092:9092 to your container.

Comment: I don't have any connection problem. As I mentioned, the problem I have is only when I try to use transactions.